# Automatic populate Excel data table.(non-vba)

Tags: excel

I am working on an excel sheet which contains a raw data table having huge amount of data. I want to populate another table automatically with specific data only. Also when i make any changes (add/delete) to the raw data table the other table should automatically updated.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qsq0.png)

As shown in example... There are four columns in the raw data table. In order column there are many same entries. Now i want to populate another table which only contains unique values only and should be updated as well as i inserts/delete the data... Please help me on this as it will be a great kind of favor.

Comment: It covers complete Row record...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivot table should be the solution to your problem. The pivot table will automatically trigger whenever the data changes in the original table.

Go to Insert-->Pivot Table-->[Select Fields You Need Summarized];

Use the SUM for the values of each of the summary fields you select. This is an option in the menu for creating the pivot table.*

That should be all you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Aguertin. I really appreciate your help. But i cant use pivot table because its a bit difficult for my co-worker to operate as they are not experts in excel. I just want to separate the Unique values from one table to another and update it automatically using simple data table format...